# How to create tile map properties ios cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, tile

I downloaded CatMaze example project from http://www.raywenderlich.com/4970/how-to-implement-a-pathfinding-with-cocos2d-tutorial.

CatMaze.tmx file has the followings..

```
<tile id="0">
   <properties>
    <property name="Bone" value="1"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
   <properties>
    <property name="Multibone" value="1"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
```

I tried to create similar properties using the map editor application but I couldn't figure that out. How can I create new tiles and properties? Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org) you can right-click just about anything. A tile in the tileset, a layer, an object, etc. The context menu provides you with the option to edit the properties.

[image]

The only exception being the Map Properties, they can be edited via the **Map -> Map Properties** menu.

**UPDATE:** an upcoming build of Tiled (v0.91 or newer) will have properties always visible in the "sidebar". Check out the daily build, it greatly simplifies working with properties.